# Rewrite catalog_category_tabs not working

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

Pretty sure I'm a HUGE noob (sorry).
So this is what I've got so far: **app/code/local/Mage/ProductLogUpdate/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_ProductLogUpdate>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Mage_ProductLogUpdate>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_category_tabs>Mage_ProductLogUpdate_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs</catalog_category_tabs>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <mage_productlogupdate>
                <class>Mage_ProductLogUpdate_Model</class>
            </mage_productlogupdate>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <mage_productlogupdate>
                        <class>mage_productlogupdate/observer</class>
                        <method>logUpdate</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </mage_productlogupdate>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Mage/ProductLogUpdate/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php**:

```
<?php
class Mage_ProductLogUpdate_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs {
    public function addTabsToCategory(){
        $this->addTab('idname', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Tab name'),
                    'content'   => "<h2>tasdf</h2>"
            ));

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

I used this model/observer from a tutorial to test if my code works
**app/code/local/Mage/ProductLogUpdate/Model/Observer.php**:

```
<?php
/* Our class name should follow the directory structure of our Observer.php model, starting from the namespace, replacing directory separators with underscores. The directory of ousr Observer.php is following:
 app/code/local/Mage/ProductLogUpdate/Model/Observer.php */
class Mage_ProductLogUpdate_Model_Observer{
    // Magento passes a Varien_Event_Observer object as the first parameter of dispatched events.
    public function logUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        // Retrieve the product being updated from the event observer
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        // Write a new line to var/log/product-updates.log
        $name = $product->getName();
        $sku = $product->getSku();
        Mage::log("{$name} ({$sku}) updated", null, 'product-updates.log');
    }
}
?>
```

And ofcourse this file **app/etc/modules/Mage_ProductLogUpdate.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_ProductLogUpdate>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mage_ProductLogUpdate>
    </modules>
</config>
```

So I'm completely lost and don't know what to do, I can't even find a lot of information about this on google and stuff.
I'm trying to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13751432/5291575), but I just don't know how to implement his code.

**EDIT:**
Changed location names from `app/code/Mage/ProductLogUpdate/..` to `app/code/local/Mage/ProductLogUpdate/..`.
Sadly enough, my problem is still not fixed.

To be clear, I'm trying to add a custom tab [here](https://gyazo.com/fb78a1a4fb78d48bfdae16385a088faf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you explain what you are trying to accomplish here?

Also try this:

**app/code/Mage/ProductLogUpdate/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php:**

If you want to use the layout you should overrule the _prepareLayout() instead because addTabsToCategory() is never defined.

```
<?php
    class Mage_ProductLogUpdate_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs {
        protected function _prepareLayout()
            parent::_prepareLayout();
            $this->addTab('idname', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Tab name'),
                    'content'   => "<h2>Hello world!</h2>",
                ));

            return $this;  
        }
    }
```

Also note: Your files are located in the wrong location.
You have placed your files under
`app/code/Mage`.

Why is this the wrong location you ask? Look at this file: `app/etc/modules/Mage_ProductLogUpdate.xml`
It's telling you that the module is located in the codePool local.

This means that your files should be located under:
app/code/**local**/Mage/......

Comment: I'm trying to add a custom tab https://gyazo.com/fb78a1a4fb78d48bfdae16385a088faf, I tried your code but still didn't work.

Comment: Ahh I see, mistake 1/X fixed. Thank you :)

Comment: No problems :), if this is the correct answer please accept this answer as correct.

Comment: I updated the question, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you maybe join my chat room (I'm dutch too). Or do you think you probably don't know the problem? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143278/magento-rewrite-room

Comment: My Stackexchange is lower then 20 rep to i cannot answer there, maybe a room in magento stackexchange (if this is possible?)

Comment: Don't know if it worked, but try this one http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58116/magento-rewrite

Comment: I've downvoted this, because such kind of things should better be done with events/observers. I'll post suggestion later ...

Answer (score 1):

Your file path and class name are not matching for this - 
**app/code/local/Mage/ProductLogUpdate/Block/Recentproducts.php**:

```
class Mage_ProductLogUpdate_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs {
    public function addTabsToCategory(){
        $this->addTab('idname', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Tab name'),
                    'content'   => "<h2>tasdf</h2>"
            ));

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

According to your class name your file name should be  `Tabs.php` and path should be `app/code/local/Mage/ProductLogUpdate/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php`